# How does DB2 BLOB do MD5?

Tags: sql, db2, md5, db2-luw

When I use the HASH function, sysibm.hex (sysibm.hash (NAME, 0)) is normal, but not if the 'NAME' is BLOB or CLOB.
I did not find an answer on support. Is my MD5 usage wrong?

Db2 11.5

```
VALUES HASH(BLOB('1',0)) --it's ok.
VALUES HEX(HASH(BLOB('1',0))) --it's wrong
```

I expect the blob to be md5

Comment: Do you mean you get sqlcode -171 (SQL0171N) when you run the HEX(HASH(BLOB('1',0)) ?

Comment: yeah,clob and blob is not normal,other it's ok

Comment: Try `HEX(CAST(HASH(BLOB('1'),0) as VARBINARY(128)))`

Comment: I just want to say, perfect!

Comment: You have to write your own Java / C function for larger LOB values unfortunately. But they are quite simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HASH function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061967.html) expects string expression as the input:

> An expression that represents the string value to be hashed. This expression must return a built-in character string, graphic string, binary string, numeric value, Boolean value, or datetime value. If the value is not a character, graphic, or binary string, it is implicitly cast to VARCHAR before the function is evaluated.

so there is some implicit casting involved. I believe this might be to the length of returned VARBINARY:

```
$ db2 "describe values hash('a',0)"

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 1

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 908   VARBINARY                64  1                                         1

$ db2 "describe values hash(blob('a'),0)"

 Column Information

 Number of columns: 1

 SQL type              Type length  Column name                     Name length
 --------------------  -----------  ------------------------------  -----------
 908   VARBINARY             32672  1                                         1
```

[HEX handles VARBINARY up to 16k](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHRBY/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000811.html):

> with a maximum length of 16 336 bytes.

so this fails:

```
db2 "values hex(hash(blob('a'),0))"
SQL0171N  The statement was not processed because the data type, length or 
value of the argument for the parameter in position "1" of routine 
"SYSIBM.HEX" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".  SQLSTATE=42815
```

but if we would trim it down, it will be OK:

```
db2 "values hex(substr(hash(blob('a'),0),1,16) )"

1                               
--------------------------------
0CC175B9C0F1B6A831C399E269772661

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`HEX(CAST(HASH(BLOB('1'),0) as VARBINARY(128)))`